# cant connect sql [php]

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin, web

Can you help fix my code.
The website simply add data, edit and delete. However when I'm trying to fill up the fields and click add, it go to a blank page. Here's my code:

```
<?php  include('server.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CRUD: CReate, Update, Delete PHP MySQL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="server.php" >
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button class="btn" type="submit" name="save" >Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>


<?php $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info"); ?>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="server.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="del_btn">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the php code.

```
 <?php 

    $name = "";
    $address = "";
    $id = "";
    $update = false;

    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
    $db = mysql_select_db("crud");

    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];

        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO info (name, address) VALUES ('$name', '$address')"); 
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Address saved"; 
        header('location: index.php');
    }

    $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info");


?>
```

It's totally blank when I click the save button. Sorry my bad english. please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand that once you are using `mysql_connect` and other you are using `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Did the state of your tables change? Any row addition/deletion?

Comment: I already tried to used the $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', password'', 'crud'); but still get the same result :(

Comment: Hi Shahlin, no row was added.

Answer (score 1):

**Check the below code and make changes to your server.php file. I hope it will work.**

```
 <?php 
        $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");
        if(!$connect){
            die('Can not connect:'.mysqli_error());
        }
        else{
            echo "Connect";
        }
        $name = "";
        $address = "";
        $id = "";
        $update = false;

        if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $sql=mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO tablename (name) VALUES ('$name')"); 
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Address saved"; 
            header('location: index.php');
        }
    ?>
```

**Change index.php file**

```
<form method="post" action="server.php" >
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button class="btn" type="submit" name="save" >Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>


    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['columnname1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['columnname2']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['yourprimarykeyid']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="server.php?del=<?php echo $row['yourprimarykeyid']; ?>" class="del_btn">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you just paste the parts that have changed?

Comment: Still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `value` attribute to your `button` tag, otherwise 
`if (isset($_POST['save']))` will fail:

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="save" value="1">Save</button>
```

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: Try enabling error reporting in PHP `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Also you could try using `mysql_connect` and `mysql_query`instead of `mysqli` functions.

Answer (score -1):

if your code include php code, it should be saved in php format and then use the localhost provider software like wampserver. copy your files in c:/wamp64/www/ directory and run your browser and type in address bar https://localhost/.... that ... is sub-directory and filename .
if open php file with double click on it, the php code in it don't execute.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't think this answers the question. Did you mean to post a comment?

Comment: Can you please extend you answer so that it answers the OP's question in more details.